# API for Processing large XLSX file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have one question. Is there any `API` that can process `xlsx` and `xls` file. The requirement is i have one excel file. i have to encrypt values of some specific columns. without affecting the format of cell like cell color, cell formula, cell date format, cell currency format, charts etc. I have used `APACHE POI` library. i did not get success. it is very slow and not working on large file. i also searched on `google` but i dint get proper result.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to POI is [JXL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/).
We used it successfully with rather large files.

Comment: thnk you Super Chafouin but it support only xls not xlsx